# How can i custom confirmation messages of Devise using Bootstrap alerts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

For confirmation messages I mean those messages which appear as example after the login and say "Successful access!". I have already custom the devise_errors_messages but I do not find the confirmation messages...please, help me!

This is helper:

```
module DeviseHelper
  def devise_error_messages!
    return '' if resource.errors.empty?

    messages = resource.errors.full_messages.map { |msg| content_tag(:li, msg) }.join
    html = <<-HTML

    <div class="alert alert-error alert-danger"> <button type="button"
    class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
      #{messages}
    </div>
    HTML

    html.html_safe
  end
end
```

...i want to edit these messages:

```
en:
  devise:
    confirmations:
      confirmed: "Your email address has been successfully confirmed."
      send_instructions: "You will receive an email with instructions for how to confirm your email address in a few minutes."
      send_paranoid_instructions: "If your email address exists in our database, you will receive an email with instructions for how to confirm your email address in a few minutes."
    failure:
      already_authenticated: "You are already signed in."
      inactive: "Your account is not activated yet."
      invalid: "Invalid %{authentication_keys} or password."
      locked: "Your account is locked."
      last_attempt: "You have one more attempt before your account is locked."
      not_found_in_database: "Invalid %{authentication_keys} or password."
      timeout: "Your session expired. Please sign in again to continue."
      unauthenticated: "You need to sign in or sign up before continuing."
      unconfirmed: "You have to confirm your email address before continuing."
    mailer:
      confirmation_instructions:
        subject: "Confirmation instructions"
      reset_password_instructions:
        subject: "Reset password instructions"
      unlock_instructions:
        subject: "Unlock instructions"
      email_changed:
        subject: "Email Changed"
      password_change:
        subject: "Password Changed"
    omniauth_callbacks:
      failure: "Could not authenticate you from %{kind} because \"%{reason}\"."
      success: "Successfully authenticated from %{kind} account."
    passwords:
      no_token: "You can't access this page without coming from a password reset email. If you do come from a password reset email, please make sure you used the full URL provided."
      send_instructions: "You will receive an email with instructions on how to reset your password in a few minutes."
      send_paranoid_instructions: "If your email address exists in our database, you will receive a password recovery link at your email address in a few minutes."
      updated: "Your password has been changed successfully. You are now signed in."
      updated_not_active: "Your password has been changed successfully."
    registrations:
      destroyed: "Bye! Your account has been successfully cancelled. We hope to see you again soon."
      signed_up: "Welcome! You have signed up successfully."
      signed_up_but_inactive: "You have signed up successfully. However, we could not sign you in because your account is not yet activated."
      signed_up_but_locked: "You have signed up successfully. However, we could not sign you in because your account is locked."
      signed_up_but_unconfirmed: "A message with a confirmation link has been sent to your email address. Please follow the link to activate your account."
      update_needs_confirmation: "You updated your account successfully, but we need to verify your new email address. Please check your email and follow the confirm link to confirm your new email address."
      updated: "Your account has been updated successfully."
```

Comment: `I have already custom the devise_errors_messages` - then show us by putting them in your question.

Comment: they are in `devise.en.yml` file

Comment: They are not into the same position...
devise_errors_messages are into the devise_helper and i can custom their layout, but where are the confirmation messages? Must I add something?

Comment: You mean you're not able see the changes in view?

Comment: I mean the normal messages of devise do not appear with the bootstrap layout. I can custom the error messages because they are into the DeviseHelper, but the other messages not. When i make a sign up, the flash message "Welcome! You have signed up successfully." appears white, not green.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this `_flashes.html.erb` in my `views/layouts/application.html.erb`
maybe this could help someone facing the same problem

```
<div id="message">
    <% if notice %>
      <div  id="inner-message-success" class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <%= notice %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
    <% if alert %>
      <div  id="inner-message-danger" class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <%= alert %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
```